# How can I do a run time analysis of my algortihm?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

Let's assume we have some services with different input parameters. First, we generate a list of numbers (cache_slices = [0.00, 0.01, ..., 1.00]) which represent the x-axis. Then, for each of these values, we calculate the backhaul_slices, which represent a linear expression w.r.t the cache_slices (backhaul_slice = a * cache_slice + b, with a and b real numbers).

After that, we calculate the absolute value of the difference between every tuple (backhaul_slice, cache_slice) in the abs_diff_list. Then, we iterate on the abs_diff_list until we find the minimum value of it and append the tuple to a list. This should be done for all of the N services.

This is the Python code for the algorithm, where gamma(i, beta) represents the function to calculate the backhaul_slice w.r.t the cache_slice:

```
cache_slices = [beta/100 for beta in range(101)]
tuples_list = []
for i in range(num_services):
    backhaul_slices = [gamma(i,beta) for beta in cache_slices]
    abs_diff_list = [abs(gamma(i,beta)-beta) for beta in cache_slices]
    for j in range(len(abs_diff_list)):
        if abs_diff_list[j] == min(abs_diff_list):
            tuples_list.append((backhaul_slices[j],cache_slices[j]))
            break
```

How can I do a runtime analysis of this algorithm (best, average and worst-case)?

Comment: Your inner `j` loop is accidentally quadratic because you're calculating the `min` each time round the loop. I guess that's the underlying reason for the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the complexity is quadratic, because `min` is recomputed at every iteration. Lifting it out of the loop will make the complexity linear. However, even that is an overkill. The constant time complexity is feasible.

You are striving to minimize `abs(gamma(i,beta)-beta)`. According to your explanation, `gamma` is a linear function: `a[i]*beta + b[i]`. The functional to minimize is therefore `abs((a[i] - 1) * beta + b[i])`. Its minimum is achieved when `beta` is near the root of `(a[i] - 1) * x + b[i] == 0`, that is `beta` must be near `-b[i] / (a[i] - 1)`. There are only two candidates to test (a corner case in which the root does not belong to the `[0.0 ... 1.0]` interval requires only one test). Constant time complexity it is.